# NSDateFormatter not giving me correct

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am displaying time. It will show me :TIME :2012-06-18 23:00:00 +0000
But after using NSDateFormatter I do not know why it is giving me 00:00:00 AM

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss a"];

NSLog(@"TIME :%@",self.startDate);

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString * _startTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"current time : %@",_startTime);
NSString * _startTime1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.startDate];
NSLog(@"Start time : %@",_startTime1);
[dateFormatter release];

**Result is**

TIME :2012-06-18 23:00:00 +0000
current time : 17:05:41 PM
Start time : 00:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of 10,000 other threads about NSDateFormatter, time zones, and mistakenly believing that NSLog displays time in the current timezone.

Comment: If I NSLog the **self.startDate ** it is giving me right date from the jason. But the problem is that after using ** NSDateFormatter ** It is showing me this ** 00:00:00 AM***. But if I use same **NSDateFormatter**  with [NSDate date] it is working perfectly.

Comment: I agree that it's working perfectly.  Everything is as one would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `NSLog` outputs the date in GMT time (notice the trailing +0000). An `NSDateFormatter` object will format the date to the specified time zone. Your `NSLog` statements show that the stored date in `self.startDate` is exactly 00:00:00 AM in at least one time zone, and the formatter is set to that time zone. The formatter will default to the time zone for the device. You could set the formatter's timezone to 0 seconds from GMT to see 23:00:00 PM out of your last `NSLog` statement:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```