# NSDate and NSDateFormatter inconsistent

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSDateFormatter not giving me correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086916/nsdateformatter-not-giving-me-correct)

I am using a NSDate which I convert to only the date using the following technique:

```
+ (NSDate *) dateOnly:(NSDate *)date
{
    long time = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    long timeMod = time % kNumSecondsInDay;
    NSTimeInterval newTime = time - timeMod;

    return [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:newTime];
}
```

This is giving me expected results:

```
    NSLog(@"Due Date:%@", _dueDate);
```

--> Due Date: 2012-11-21 00:00:00 +0000

However, when I use the date formatter, it gives me one day previous:

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:_dueDate];
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
```

--> Result: 11/20/12

What gives?

Comment: Time zone is what gives.  (Duplicate of about 100 other "NSDateFormater doesn't work" threads.)

Comment: I see the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time zone. The date is midnight on 11/21, UTC; if your time zone is behind UTC, then it'll be 11/20.

Comment: I see the problem, thank you.